# MySQL select by a combination of an Id and a superstring

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, indexing, substring

This is related to an old question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604169/how-do-i-optimize-a-database-for-superstring-queries), but this one is different.

I have a MySQL table of web "articles" from many "customers". The table is named *ArticleTable* and It has several fields, two of which are:

*CustomerId* = the Id of the customer owning the article.
   *ArticleId* = **substring** of the article's url, uniquely identifying the article's url.

Now, given a customer Id + complete url of a webpage in runtime, I need to find whether I have a customer's article in the table, matching this complete url. The obvious query I can think of is:

```
SELECT * FROM ArticleTable
WHERE CustomerId = givenCustomerId
AND 'givenCompleteUrl' LIKE CONCAT('%', ArticleId, '%')
```

The real-life situation is that I may have many customers, but only a few articles per customer. However, in the above query I don't have full control over MySQL's select mechanism. So the questions are:

1. Using the above query syntax, if I define my indexes correctly, will MySQL be smart enough to look through only the few rows of the givenCustomerId? (i.e., not decide to first filter by ArticleId and only then by CustomerId)
2. Alternatively, will it be faster to simply select all givenCustomerId rows into PHP and do the string matching myself?
3. If I still rely on MySQL to perform the full query, which indexes should I define to optimize the above query?

Comment: MySQL should be bright enough to search by the customer id using indexes, then check the url.

Answer (score 0):

I hate your second where clause. It might be slow and actually incorrect in some cases. It's much better to extract the ArticleId in PHP and then simply do:

```
SELECT * FROM ArticleTable
WHERE CustomerId = ?
AND ArticleId = ?
```

To answer your question, I think it's sufficient to index `(ArticleID, CustomerId)` if you use this query.